# С помощью google extensions хочу передать данные с одной вкладки в другую

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-app

С помощью google extensions хочу передать данные с одной вкладки в другую (с сайта1 в сайт2, но домены разные). localStorage не помогает, т.к. домены разные.

Пробовал `chrome.tabs.query` и `chrome.tabs.create`.

В какую сторону копаться?

*p.s. для примера хочу передать значение title с одного сайта на другую*

Comment: делайте background скрипт. один контент скрипт передает в бакграунд то что хочет (через chrome.runtime.sendMessage), а второй так же забирает. или background его сам находит и высылает

Comment: Насколько я понял, таким способом он не запоминает данные, которые хочу передать с одной вкладки в другую, как только откроем другую вкладку становится none (напоминаю: домены разные). Может есть еще варианты, которые гарантированно будут перенести данные с одного сайта в другую? (без потери конечно же)

Comment: Используйте сервер для этого. С вебсокетами.

Comment: @РашитВарисов background скрипт (который в манифесте описан как `"background": { "scripts": [ "xxx.js" ] }`остается в памяти пока открыто хотя бы одно окно браузера. прямого доступа к страницам он не имеет. Но контент/popup скрипты могут обмениваться с ним информацией.

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Как передать со своего google расширения данные с одной вкладки в другую?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787449/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-google-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E)