# Как передать со своего google расширения данные с одной вкладки в другую?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

С помощью своего расширения google хром хочу передать данные с одного домена в другую. А именно, текст с одного сайта в другую. localStorage сразу отпадает.

Попытался через `chrome.tabs.query`, `chrome.tabs.get`, `chrome.tabs.create`, но не получается, передает `null`.

Какие есть рабочие варианты, чтобы можно было передать значении с одного сайта в другую с помощью своего плагина google chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкладки не имеют возможности общаться между собой напрямую. 
Для передачи данных необходимо использовать *background*-скрипт в качестве брокера сообщений.

Пример расширения:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name":"Test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description":"",
    "version":"1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
// Прослушивание сообщений от всех вкладок
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    /*
     * msg = {domain, text}
     */

    chrome.tabs.query({
        url: msg.domain // маска доменого имени для выбора вкладки
    }, function(result) {
        if(result.length) {
            var tab = result[0]; // первая найденная вкладк
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg.text); 
        }
    });
});
```

Тут можно использовать один контент-скрипт для всех вкладок. 
В примере ниже 
вкладка на домене yandex.ru отправляет сообщение вкладке с доменом google.com.

Обратите внимание, что для указания получаетля используется маска URL. Метод [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) поддерживает такого рода [URL-pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

**content-script.js**

```js
if(document.location.host.includes('yandex')) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        domain: '*://*.google.com/*',
        text: 'Hello from yandex'
    });
}


// Вкладка с google.com примет сообщение
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```